# GGplot Boxplot vs boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do a boxplot with GGplot and I get only one box when I do a ggplot like

```
ggplot(data_frame, aes(x=probs, y=values)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color="red", fill="orange", alpha=0.5)
```

while I should be getting 3 boxes when I do the normal plot:

```
boxplot(values ~ probs, data = data_frame,
        xlab = "Probabilities", 
        ylab = "Values (1Q, Mean, Median, StdDev, 3Q)", 
        main = "1Q, Mean, Median, StdDev, 3Q", 
        col = c("green","yellow","purple"))

Sample data:
> head(data_frame,20)
   values probs
1  16.000   0.3
2  18.000   0.3
3  18.000   0.3
4   3.550   0.3
5  20.000   0.3
6  27.000   0.5
7  30.000   0.5
8  30.000   0.5
9   3.873   0.5
10 33.000   0.5
11 46.000   0.8
12 48.000   0.8
13 48.000   0.8
14  3.098   0.8
15 50.000   0.8
```

Any pointers is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Geom_boxplot's X axis must be categorical to get it like you want to.
One solution is to transform "probs" as character:

```
ggplot(data_frame, aes(x=as.character(probs), y=values)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color="red", fill="orange", alpha=0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you are looking for...

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(probs), y=values)) + 
    geom_boxplot(color="red", fill="orange", alpha=0.5)
```